# Flutterflow: generating Id values

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutterflow

Using Flutterflow I want to auto generate an Id in when creating a firebase document. Here is an example:

> create new document in collection "fruits".
>
> ```
> name: "Apple"
> fruitID: "yTMG0dDUGHDpyqjegU3i"
> where the document reference is "/fruits/yTMG0dDUGHDpyqjegU3i"
> ```

My question is, what variable to set in the fruitID field to achieve this. Or ist there a function that can do that?

Thanks!

I tried to find a solution via a custom function, but I could not implement it in the document creation UI. Also there was no reference link available.

Comment: I'm not clear.  Are you saying that you want to create a document with a random ID, and put that ID string in a field of that same document?

Comment: FlutterFlow will auto-assign a string of random letters/numbers for your Document ID whenever you use the backend action to "Create Document". If that is what you are wanting, then you don't need any custom action; just use what is provided.